# Seeking Guidance on Creating a Staggered GridView with Dynamic Height for Maintaining Rectangular Image Shapes - in Flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, gridview, staggered-gridview

**I want to add images in a GridView so that they should divide their heights in a way that maintains the rectangular shape of the GridView. Additionally, I would like the images to be arranged in a staggered manner.**

that's how I want it to look

[image]